# created my custom exception unable to catch it properly

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

here i am creating my custom exception 
and want to throw exception on divide method for wrong input
till then it was fine i am able to throw my custom exception but problem in catching it 
code as follows

```
class A extends Exception {
    A(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}

class Emp {
    int a;
    int b;

    void divide(int a, int b) throws A {
        if (b == 0) {
            throw new A("super exception is there");
        } else
            System.out.println(a / b);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Emp m = new Emp();
        try {
            m.divide(10, 0);
        } catch (A e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

it giving me error main method not found me A class
unable to figure out why  this is happening

Comment: At least format your code so it's marginally readable. You also need to include at least some of the error dialogue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks to fix a working code.

Comment: A stylistic suggestion: Your custom `Exception` should be named something like `AException` or `CustomDivideByZeroException`, so that other developers (and yourself later on) can easily tell that this is an `Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, your `main()` method is defined in the `Emp` class rename your .java file to `Emp.java`. It's probably `A.java` right now because that's why Java is looking for the `main()` method in class `A`.

Comment: Yep, it's this.  Just copied and pasted it into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried your code and it is working fine. returning the following result:

```
A: super exception is there
```

What is the name of your java file. I have named it as `Emp.java` as `Emp` class is containing `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your main-Method is in your Emp class not in the A class.

Name your sourcefile "Emp.java" and compile it with "javac Emp.java" if you use the command line and than run it with "java Emp".